# Why isn't my notification working in SWIFT3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I setup a notification using a UIDatePicker. When I run the application on my phone, notification is not working.

What's the problem ?

My code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var timer = Timer()    
    var time = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scheduleLocalNotification()
    }


    func scheduleLocalNotification() {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        let dateTime = datePicker.date
        notification.alertAction = "Call"
        notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now"
        notification.fireDate = dateTime
        notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }


    @IBAction func pushNotification(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let AlertView = UIAlertController(title: "Time for your call!", message: "Press go to continue", preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        AlertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(AlertView, animated: true, completion: nil)    
    }
 }
```

Comment: What triggers your `pushNotification` action?

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**iOS 8 - iOS9:**

1. As @FrederikFrandsen said, you have to register your Application for user notifications first:

   ```
   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)        
   UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   ```
2. Then you can handle local notifications in your `AppDelegate` by implementing following `UIApplicationDelegate` function:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
       // handle your local notification here
   }
   ```

**iOS 10:**

1. In your AppDelegate add the new `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`:

   ```
   import UserNotifications

   extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
       func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
           completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
       }

       func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
           completionHandler()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set the delegate of `UNUserNotificationCenter` (e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`):

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   ```
3. Request authorization:

   ```
   let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
       // handle error
   })
   ```
4. Trigger your user notifications:

   ```
   let components = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: datePicker.date)

   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "title"
   content.body = "body"
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myRequest", content: content, trigger: trigger)

   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
       // handle error
   })
   ```

Comment: what does "handle your local notification here" mean? how can i show the notification there? scheduling there causes an infinite loop.

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan it's the body of the function that gets called when the app receives a `UILocalNotification` until iOS 9. You don't schedule your notification from that place - you can handle it at that point. Starting from iOS 10 you can use the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to display the Notification in your app. Before iOS 10 you have to use custom UI to show notifications when you are already in the app.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10, UILocalNotification is deprecated. You won't be able to get it to work property. You need to migrate your code to use the new User Notifications framework.

Comment: Isn't this just a problem when using a Deployment Target of iOS 10 or later? I never had issues with deprecated code that is supported by the Deployment Target version.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.swift

You need this here:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` is not needed for local Notifications - but yeah. That should work. @krish please be aware that you don't see the notification when your app is open.